# Reset function once you already click it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi im new on js and honestly speaking we're just starting learning js on our school. What i want to do is once i already click it it will be reset and remove the class again. "myClass has a display none"

```
   $(function() {
        $("body").click(function() {
            $(".parela").addClass('myClass');
        });
    });
```

Comment: So you want to toggle the visibility? Click once and it shows, click again and it hides etc?

Comment: `addClass` => `toggleClass` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**toggleclass**](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```
$(function() {
        $("body").click(function() {
            $(".parela").toggleClass('myClass');
        });
    });
```

Comment: Capital `C` is important in the function name (but at least you provided a link to the docs)!

Comment: @Rhumborl thanks for pointing it out.I have edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

You want to use toggleClass() which will toggle the class on and off depending on the click. note that for the demo below - I created the button that toggles the class on the button click.

Another way of doing it - since the only effect is to hide the element - is just .toggle() which toggles the display state without the use of the added class. The following snippet shows both methods.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#toggleButton").click(function() {
     $(".parela").toggleClass('myClass');
   });
        
  $("#toggleButton2").click(function() {
      $(".parela2").toggle();
   });
 });
```

```css
.myClass{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Using .toggleClass('myClass')</p>
<button type="button" id="toggleButton">clickMe</button>

<span class="parela"> Visible</span>
<hr/>
<p>Using just .toggle()</p>
<button type="button" id="toggleButton2">clickMe</button>

<span class="parela2"> Visible</span>
```

Comment: thank you so much and one last question is there any way once you click a link "a href=""> it will click the body of the page ?

Comment: no worries - and regarding the clicking the link - it will direct you to the destination indicated by the href. You can put # as the href - but I would probably suggest you look at what you are clicking and why you are clicking it. An <a> with a href is best used to navigate to a different page or to an anchor within the same page. Technically speaking - the <a> will be located within the body - so you could think of it as clicking the body - but you really need to think about the best structure for the click - and if its not to navigate to a different area - its probably not an <a> element.

Answer (score 1):

Use toggleClass, so at every click it will be added/removed automatically

```
$(function() {
    $("body").click(function() {
        $(".parela").toggleClass('myClass');
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you so much and one last question is there any way once you click a link "a href=""> it will click the body of the page ?

Answer (score 0):

You can you use some sort of 'flag' variable to control the state.
You can name it whatever you want and make if statement to make decisions accordingly.

```
   $(function() {
        var flag = false;
        $("body").click(function() {
            if(!flag) {
                $(".parela").addClass('myClass'); 
                flag = true;
            } else {
                $(".parela").removeClass('myClass');
                flag = false;
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Why bother with all of this flags in if statements when you have a simple `toggleClass`  (And 3 different upvoted answers that use `toggleClass`)?

Comment: Sometimes you need more than just toggle class.

Comment: OK, fair enough - But if you show a more complex example you _might_ also consider demonstrating the `hasClass` to check it instead of using a flag because the OP say that they are just started learning JS (I'll upvote it anyway because I agree with what you say)